# Crontab Shell Script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, cron

Iam facing some issue with shell script which is processed through crontab.
I Get email with these errors:

```
checkprocess.sh: line 2: 
: command not found
checkproces: line 4: syntax error near unexpected token `in
'
checkproces: line 4: `case $PROCESS_COUNT in
```

Here is the Shell Script Code:

```
#!/bin/sh

PROCESS_COUNT=$(ps -fu root | grep serv45svp | grep -v grep | wc -l)
case $PROCESS_COUNT in
0) /root/pro3/serv45svp &
;;
1) #OK, Program Running once
;;
*) #OK, program Running multiple time
;;
esac
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do I get "syntax error near unexpected token 'do'"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841235/why-do-i-get-syntax-error-near-unexpected-token-do)

Answer (score 1):

Your script has `CRLF` at the end of the lines, instead of `LF`. If you edit a Unix script on Windows, you have to fix it with `dos2unix`.

On Unix, lines end with a single `LF` character. On DOS/Windows, lines end with a `CR` character followed by a `LF` character.

If you copy a file from Windows to Unix in binary mode, the line endings will not be converted. Unix doesn't recognize the `CR` characters as being anything special, it thinks they're part of the command name or arguments. This causes errors because the commands and arguments shouldn't end with this extra character.

The `dos2unix` utility removes these extraneous `CR` characters.

Comment: Sorry, Iam a newbie to linux so could you please brief your answer.

Comment: Added some explanation.